# Can't save image to website images folder

Tags: c#

I've been able to save a bitmap image as a .jpg to a file system path but can't figure out how to save it to my website (MS VS Express 2013 for Web/c#) images folder:

```
// Works 
img.Save("C:\Upload\looky.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

// Doesn't work 
img.Save("images/looky.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg); img.Save("~/images/looky.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

any ideas?

```
// Ultimate goal (which works if the file is moved manually): 
this.img.ImageUrl = "images/looky.jpg";
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It was just a generic GDI graphics error. Got it fixed now! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the full path:

```
img.Save(Server.MapPath("~/images/looky.jpg"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Even if the file "moves" as you stated there is still a real, physical path to that location. `Server.MapPath` takes care of that, but of course you'll also need to worry about write permissions.

Comment: That's done it. I'm grateful, spent a lot of time on that one and never saw anything about Server.MapPath!